Update SQL connection string when deploying updates to .NET Aspire app
I've deployed a .NET Aspire app to Azure using the azd up cmdlet. During the deployment step, a connection string was requested to an Azure SQL database. The app and its connection to the database works as expected.
I now need to change the connection string to point to a different database. I found the connection string secrets in my Azure Container App in the Azure portal and updated them there. But when deploying updates using azd deploy the connection string is reverted to its original value.
I can see in the config.json file of my environment that the connection strings are read from a vault, identified by a GUID. But we have no Azure Key Vault instances in our tenant with that ID, so I'm not sure where this vault is being referenced.
How can I update my connection string to a new value that will ensure subsequent deployments will use it and not override it with the value initially provided?

Have you checked whether any KeyVault was unintentionally created within your Azure Portal? my guess it is created automatically during deployment. Also I would check the permissions to see these specific keyvaults, try with a admin account.

I thought that as well but couldn't find one in the provisioned Resource Group or under the Azure Key Vault blade. I'm a global admin, so should see all the resources, but I had another colleague with admin rights check and he couldn't find a vault with that GUID either.

I think you need to run azd pipeline config which will take the values in the config.json and add the JSON to the AZD_INITIAL_ENVIRONMENT_CONFIG env var in the pipeline. It's also possible to remove, manually, the vault Uri, which isn't to do with Key Vault but points to user-secrets, I believe, and put your connection string in there in plain text. Then add that JSON to the AZD_INITIAL_ENVIRONMENT_CONFIG in your Pipeline's Library variable group. Not ideal but could get you further forward.

Thank you @Boggin. The initial deployments were done directly from the terminal on my local machine, so there isn't a pipeline involved. This is useful info for when the app is moved to ADO though! The vault ID doesn't match the secret ID, so honestly not sure what this refers to. In any event, I'm going to try move the connection strings to secrets in a Key Vault instead, providing a consistent management plane for future changes.
